# dynamic web reference URL

Tags: c#, soap, ssis, wsdl

I'm using a SAOP API from SSIS C# script.
My question is how can I change my Web Reference on the go from a variable?

I found in web Reference settings this option: [image]

but my question is how can change this value in the C# script?

I tried doing the following but I get an error:

```
 PS.Url = "http://" + Variables.WebServiceURL + "/WebService/services/PlanningService";
```

the error message:

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>      at SC_15f094dba1c3453e812875c8714e03b4.PlanningService.PlanningService.getPlanningAreas() in c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\vsta\802c7440ec9144df97b2df214844351c\Web References\PlanningService\Reference.cs:line 460
>      at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows() in c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\vsta\802c7440ec9144df97b2df214844351c\main.cs:line 127
>      at UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap) in c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\vsta\802c7440ec9144df97b2df214844351c\ComponentWrapper.cs:line 49
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)

Comment: when you create in instance of the web reference  object in code you can change the `Url` property (I believe it's called `Url`)

Comment: after reading the auto generated proxy classes you'll find it

Comment: I'm not sure what that means and how i do that

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonesopolis commented, i managed to change the reference via the Url field with a parameter that's coming from SSIS.

so this worked:

```
PS.Url = "http://" + Variables.WebServiceURL + "/WebService/services/PlanningService";
```

The web server was down, that is why i was getting the error.